# How to write sleep function for my controlled DateTime?

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime, time, sleep

I created a variable

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

I am increasing time a second in an iteration of while loop.

```
while True:
    current_time = current_time + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

current_time is a global variable. I am using it as time in my modules. I want to sleep some functions based on this time.
but if I use

```
time.sleep()
```

this will use system time.
So How can I create a sleep function that depends on my current_time?

**Edit:-** I am implementing an algorithm, storing a value lets call it scheduling time. I want to wait for function up to scheduling time and on time execute the function. There are some functions that will update the scheduling time. So it is a repetitive process. I look for the scheduler library but didn't find anything to use, current_time as time.

I don't want to use system time directly, for me current_time is the time of the system/program. So current_time will increase with speed of the while loop. I am just running while loop without any relation with time, just want to update my time faster because I am using the code to generate months of data in hours. I want to keep my code as virgin as possible. I want to generate data based on this algorithm and will replace my artificial time with the real system time for production use.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate a process over time? If so, you might want to use a time-ordered event queue/heap instead. If not, I don't think I understand your use-case. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you need current time?

Comment: I am implementing an algorithm, storing a value lets call it scheduling time.  I want to wait for function up to scheduling time and on time execute the function. There are some functions that will update the scheduling time. So it is a repetitive process. I look for the scheduler library but didn't find anything to use,  current_time as time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sleep until `current_time` is reached, you can do:

```py
while datetime.datetime.now() <= current_time:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Assuming I'm understanding correctly that your `current_time` is greater than the actual current time from `datetime.datetime.now()`.

Comment: I don't want to use system time directly, for me current_time is the time of the system/program.  So current_time will increase with speed of the while loop.  in your answer, it sleeps for 1 second of real system time. but I want to make it sleep for 1 second of my time( whose clock runs with speed of while loop).

Comment: @Hungrywolf, I see what you mean now. How do you define one second of while loop time?

Comment: I am just running while loop without any relation with time, just want to update my time faster because I am using the code to generate months of data in hours. I want to keep my code as virgin as possible. I want to generate data based on this algorithm and will replace my artificial time with the real system time for production use. @dcacat

Comment: Ok, makes sense now. I have no other suggestion apart from maybe time your loop, find out how long it's taking and sleep for that amount of time. You can sleep for fractions of seconds with sleep()

Comment: I ran the while loop for a minute. 1st time = 6764 cycles, 2nd time =7014 cycles. So it will not work.

Comment: I was thinking to time it on every run and use that as the sleep amount.